# Map over csv in python

Tags: python, csv, lambda, dictionary

I'm trying to use "map" on a csv file in python.

However, the line `map(lambda x: x, reseller_csv)` gives nothing.

I've tried iterating over the csv object, and it works fine and can print the rows.

Here's the code.

```
# imports
import csv

# Opens files
ifile = open('C:\Users\josh.SCL\Desktop\Records.csv', 'r')
ofile = open('C:\Users\josh.SCL\Desktop\RecordsNew.csv', 'w')
resellers_file = open('C:\Users\josh.SCL\Desktop\Reseller.csv', 'r')


# Setup CSV objects
csvfile = csv.DictReader(ifile, delimiter=',')
reseller_csv = csv.DictReader(resellers_file, delimiter=',')

# Get names only in resellers
resellers = map(lambda x: x.get('Reseller'), reseller_csv)
```

Comment: Might want to show your code for how you create `reseller_csv` even though I assume it's some sort of csv reader object from the `csv` module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A csv.DictReader is a use-once gadget. You probably ran it a second time.

```
>>> import csv
>>> iterable = ['Reseller,cost', 'fred,100', 'joe,99']
>>> reseller_csv = csv.DictReader(iterable)
>>> map(lambda x: x.get('Reseller'), reseller_csv)
['fred', 'joe']
>>> map(lambda x: x.get('Reseller'), reseller_csv)
[]
>>>
```

While we're here:

(1) [Python 2.x] Always open csv files in **BINARY** mode.
[Python 3.x] Always open csv files in text mode (the default), and use `newline=''`

(2) If you insist on hardcoding file paths in Windows, use r"...." instead of "...", or use forward slashes -- otherwise `\n` and `\t` will be interpreted as control characters.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
>>> data = ["name,age", "john,32", "bob,45"]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.get("name"), csv.DictReader(data))) # Python 3 so using list to see values.
['john', 'bob']
```

Are you sure you get any data at all from your `DictReader`? Do you read any data from it prior to that, exhausting the reader perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First on your specific problem: try checking if there is actually a key named 'Reseller', chances are its there with different capitalization or extra space. See list of all the keys (assuming non-exhausted DictReader):

```
>>> csvfile.next().keys()
```

Otherwise the `map()` should work fine. But i'd argue it's more readable (and faster!) done like this:

```
resellers = [x['Reseller'] for x in reseller_csv]
```

Comment: The OP's code uses `x.get('Reseller')` which returns `None` if the specified key doesn't exist ... so he'd get `[None, None, ...]`. Moreover, he said `map(lambda x: x, reseller_csv)` returned "nothing" (presumably `[]`) whereas under your wrong-key hypothesis, the result would have been a list of dicts.